# Bisection algorithm

Tags: r

I don’t know how to do this exercise.

I would like to use the bisection algorithm to find the value to the inverse function for `y=x^3`, for the specific value `y0=27`.

The desired precision is ten to the minus four.

Comment: First make sure you understand the bisection method, then implement it in whichever language you are supposed to be using. Which part are you having difficulty with (algorithm or implementation ?) ?

Comment: This is an exercise to solve with R, is the first time that I see the bisection.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must solve the equation

```
f(x) = y - x³ = 0
```

where `y = 27`.

The bisection method requests that you find two values of `x` that bracket the roots, i.e. `f(x0)<0` and `f(x1)>0` or conversely.

You can search such values starting from `x0 = 0`, evaluating `f(0)` and increasing `x1` until `f(x1)` takes the opposite sign (you can increase following an arithmetic sequence, but a geometric one could be faster).

When you have found the change of sign, you can start the bisection iterations.

The stopping criterion is easy, as you know the size of the successive steps: stop when the last two `x` differ by less than `0.0001`.